# Is there a performance gain when decoding json using object_hook?

Tags: python, json

Given the following JSON structure:

```
[{'name': 'test', 'age': 19, 'extra': {'new_field': 1, 'new_field_2': 2}}]
```

and this python structure:

```
Record = namedtuple('Record', ['name', 'age', 'extra'])
```

To decode the json string into python object, I can do:

```
def decoder_one(raw_data):
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    for record in data:
        yield Record(**data)
```

as well as:

```
def _data_hook(data):
    if 'extra' in data:
        return Record(**data)
    return data

def decoder_two(raw_data):
    return json.loads(raw_data, object_hook=_data_hook)
```

Is there a benefit in using one over the other?